# Synchronize azure devops plugin with cloned project using pycharm plugin

Tags: azure-devops, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I have azure project and i cloned it manually to my PC

I downloaded azure devOps plugin to pycharm

I want to synchronize my local project to azure devOps to be able to create merge request from pycharm

After working around I found only cloning remote to new project but I didn't find any thing about synchronizing the previously cloned project with the azure devOps

Comment: I tried to use the old folder with its own git folder and deployment settings  to initialize the azure devops but i failed to do this , So  I had to clone the repo again  to new project and set the configurations again the deployment servers .

Answer (score 1):

> Synchronize azure devops plugin with cloned project using pycharm plugin

You can try to open your previously cloned project in the pycharm, then select `update the project...` under the `VCS` tab:

[image]

Which will pull the latest changes from the Azure Devops. If you do any change in your local with pycharm, you could also use the option `commit...` to submit the changes and use `git push` to push the changes to the Azure Devops.

Besides, if your previously cloned project is not in the source control, you will need to add it into the source control, or you can add that project to the repo in the local.

Hope this helps.